# JsonMappingException: Already had POJO for (java.lang.Integer)

Tags: java

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize entities using Jackson 2.9.8 and I'm getting this exception.

My entities don't have ids attributes I'm using the `hashCode()` method of the parent class.

I called it `SerializationId`.

The exception that I get is:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already had POJO for id
>   (java.lang.Integer) [[ObjectId: key=-23395637,
>   type=com.palmyra.test.TestIdGeneratorUMLX, scope=UMLX]]
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.SimpleObjectIdResolver.bindItem(SimpleObjectIdResolver.java:24)

In the JSON I found `SerializationId` in the parent and in the child.

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: It would be important to post the entity code and the json.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = MyGenerator.class, property = "SerializationId ", scope = X.class)
public class X extends Z{
    private Map<String,Y> maps;

       // ... other columns, getters & setters
}
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = MyGenerator.class, property = "SerializationId ", scope = Y.class)
public class y extends Z{
    private Y myY;
       // ... other columns, getters & setters
}
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = MyGenerator.class, property = "SerializationId ", scope = Z.class)
public class Z {
    private String fullName;   
//this method return the hashcode of the fullName which is unique .
public int hashcode(){
}

       // ... other columns, getters & setters
}


public class MyGenerator extends ObjectIdGenerator<Z>{
generateId(forPojo){
//getting the hashcode
forPojo.hashcode();
}


}
```